# Customize JSON collection name in Serializer

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

When accessing API resources like `/api/users/` which list/search a resource Ember Data expectects the response to be in this format:

```
{
  "users": [{
    "name": "Rails"
  }, {
    "name": "Omakase"
  }]
}
```

but my response looks like this:

```
{
  "results": [{
    "name": "Rails"
  }, {
    "name": "Omakase"
  }]
}
```

How can I tell my Serializer to turn results into users?

The following Serialzer renames single attributes but not the whole list as shown above:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    "users" : "results",
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do it for you, dont change attributes, just these two methods for extracting single models and arrays of models. You take the payload.results property and process it further, instead of the default payload.

```
    extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
        return Array.prototype.map.call(payload.results, function(hash) {
            return this.normalize(type, hash, payload.type);
        }, this);
    },

    extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, recordId) {
        return this.normalize(type, payload.results, payload.type);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna give it a try tomorrow. Why the extractSingle-function?

Comment: Because i assumed your api has the same structure for a request for a single user like /user/<userid>. I guess your api then returns {results { id : user_id, ...} }. If not just change it or skip it,

Comment: That's what I did. Works perfectly and I learned something. Thank you.